# Travelling to the USA with a laptop that won't hold charge

Tags: usa, uk, luggage

I'm doing a round trip between the US and the UK with Delta, and intend to take my laptop. Unfortunately, the battery recently began to stop holding charge: when I plug in the charger and turn on my laptop, it works fine, but as soon as I remove or turn off the charger my laptop shuts down.

Will I still be able to take my laptop onto the plane in hand luggage and/or hold luggage?

The reason I ask is because I've been on domestic flights where they've required smartphones/tablets/laptops to be at least 20% charged when boarding. [Here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/terrorism-in-the-uk/10952671/Airport-security-you-wont-fly-to-the-US-if-your-mobile-phone-battery-is-dead.html) is a somewhat old link regarding minimum charge of electronics on flights to the US.

Comment: Now that you've received an answer, I am just asking out of curiosity: why did you think that your airline cares about your laptop's battery being damaged or not?

Comment: I've been on domestic flights where they've required smartphones/tablets/laptops to be at least 20% charged for whatever reason. A somewhat old link regarding flights to the US: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/terrorism-in-the-uk/10952671/Airport-security-you-wont-fly-to-the-US-if-your-mobile-phone-battery-is-dead.html

Comment: +1. Interesting. Please add this comment to your question to get more upvotes. Because I think your reasoning and that link are essential for your question.

Comment: That link seems like it should be useful, but the answers aren't so helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I flew with Delta to the US last week. In the queue to the checkin counter (when they put those little stickers on the back of your passport) I was asked if all electronics where sufficiently charged to be able to demonstrate that they were working devices. However, at no point was I asked to actually do that.

My conclusion: you could be asked to power up the laptop but won't always. As far as I understood, what they mainly are concerned about is that you would replace the battery with explosives. For this reason I assume that powering up using the power cord will not be sufficient.

I was flying from Western Europe, but not the UK. I am not sure if this only applies to hand luggage or also to checked luggage.

Answer (score 2):

If the battery doesn't work so you know you'll have to use the power cord anyway, could you remove the battery and leave it at home for your trip? I understood the issue to be that batteries were being used to conceal explosives, so if you don't have a battery at all that might be OK.

Comment: Whilst your understanding about the batteries concealing explosives may well be correct, you're assuming that if you showed a security person that there were no batteries, they would let you through. I suspect that way more likely is: "It can't be turned on, you can't take it through" "But there aren't any batteries" "My list says you can't take it, if it doesn't turn on" "But there isn't a risk" "My list says..." "But!..." "Sir, leave or I'll have you arrested".